# Nextflow errors running on HPC: /bin/bash: .command.run: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bioinformatics, hpc, nextflow

Having some trouble running a nextflow pipeline on a HPC server which I think comes from the scratch space.

Some background on the server:
User's are encouraged to not use their own `/home/user/` directories and are encouraged to use `/home/project-directories`.

The server runs CentOS Linux 7 and has 3 separate nodes.

When building my pipeline I relied on my own `/home/user/` directory for testing - the pipeline runs great. It was not until I moved to a `/home/project-directory/` that I ran into issues.
I did not set scratch to anything within the config, workflow or modules and relied on the default value.

Most processes within the pipeline rely on singularity images stored in a central location on the server: `/home/opt/singularity_containers/`. (permissions set to 777)

**I have one process which runs immediately, and does not rely on a singularity container, and completes without error under all the conditions below.**

However, any process relying on a singularity container gives the errors below.

When running the pipeline in `/home/project-directory/` I get the error: `/bin/bash: .command.run: No such file or directory.`

I tried the following:

- Within a given process setting: `scratch /home/scratch` (this directory exists)

  - Does not work, still get `/bin/bash: .command.run: No such file or directory`
- Within a given process setting: `scratch false`

  - Does not work, still get `/bin/bash: .command.run: No such file or directory`
- Within a given process setting: `scratch true`

  - Does not work, still get `/bin/bash: .command.run: No such file or directory`

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this?
Maybe I am going in the wrong direction with the scratch directory and the problem is coming from something else.

**EDIT: Solution found**
Got a solution! However, if anyone can add insight I would appreciate it - CharGPT for the "win".
The solution was to add these lines to the nextflow.config file after enabled = true:

```
singularity {

    enabled = true
    singularity.enabled = true
    singularity.autoMounts = true
}
```

My confusion is why this is different when running in a user home directory versus a shared home project directory.

Comment: I do not know Nextflow well but my guess is this because Singularity *always* mounts your home directory unless told otherwise. The additional options probably tell it to mount other filesystems and/or your current working directory. These additional mounts are only needed when you are working outwith your home directory.

Comment: How did you tell Nextflow to use Singularity without those lines in the first place?